# Line break in Label when binding text from property coming from mvvm - StringFormat

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

I using `Label.FormattedText` on `Label` for `ListView`s `Cell` for multiple text on a single control. I want a line break and text coming from mvvm property. This how I want to format the text

```
Text=" linebreak + property_text + | "
```

This code trying but that gives an error in xaml.

```
<Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding name}" >
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding name}"/>
            <Span Text="{Binding balance, StringFormat='&#x0a; = {0:N}' | }" FontSize="Micro"/>
            <Span Text="Insufficiant balance" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Micro"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

It shows some syntax error here `StringFormat='&#x0a; = {0:N}' | }`.

Below output I am looking for

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must add this namespace on the xaml first:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
```

And then in your formatted text use it like this:

```
<Label FontSize="Medium">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding balance}" FontSize="Micro" />
            <Span Text=" | " />
            <Span Text="{x:Static system:Environment.NewLine"} />
            <Span Text="Insufficiant balance" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Micro"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own value converter to do this too:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MyBalanceConverter x:Key="balanceConv" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
           VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="{Binding CardName}" />
                <Span Text="{Binding Balance, Converter={StaticResource balanceConv}}"
                      FontSize="Micro" />
                <Span Text=" | "
                      FontSize="Micro" />
                <Span Text="Insufficient Funds"
                      TextColor="Red"
                      FontSize="Micro" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Where the `IValueConverter` conversion is defined:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return string.Format("\n{0:C2}", (double)value);
}
```

This gives you:

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: This should be accepted as answer .